Can I use spray adhesive to attach a tarp to a metal roof?
I need to cover a metal roof until spring. I can't use anything heavy or use nails. Would spray adhesive work to attach a tarp to the roof?

"spray adhesive" covers a wide range of items. Any adhesive will work well with some things and not work well (or sometimes actually destroy things) with other materials. Pictures of the roof and tarp would help.

I can't imagine it would.  Even if it did how many cans would you need for a tarp.

yes you can, getting it off afterwards could be a problem

As said above, "spray adhesive" could mean many things. I doubt anything in an aerosol can isn't going to stick strong enough. Generally speaking, the more info and photos you provide with a question here, the better results you get. What does the roof look like? How big? Does it have a gable? I'm down to help you troubleshoot this.

What about a large netting / mesh - like a fishing net?

What are you planning to do to the roof in the spring?

I doubt a real spray adhesive would work for that.  You need some kind of goopy texture, not an aerosol.

@SolarMike, most tarps have integrated mesh already. I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Welcome to DIY! If you'll give us a little more context, such as why the roof needs to be covered (ie protection from what?) and something about its condition and future plans, then you might get answers that are more useful in solving your problem. Perhaps a tarp is not a good choice for solving your problem - spring is 5 months away, and tarps in the sun and wind tend to have a very short lifetime. Adhesives too can fail early depending on their exposure to elements.

Probably not. There's almost certainly some spray adhesive that would work, but if you're referring to the rattle cans at your hardware store, no. They dry hard and would simply rip loose in a wind. You'd need something gummy and thick. You probably don't want to pay for that, mess with it, or have it all over your roof.
So, alternatives...
There is available a protective, self-adhesive poly sheeting designed to protect carpeting during a renovation project. Maybe that would suit your needs. You might want to pin down the edges with a very strong tape for added security.
You could also use ice-and-water barrier for the specific vulnerable areas. It'll leave black residue, though. For smaller areas, window flashing tape is good and sticky.
